# Forwarding Error logs from ElasticSearch to Slack

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, logging, kibana, filebeat

I have spring boot app and configured logging with filebeat, ElasticSearch and Kibana.

This application generate multiple log levels including INFO, WARN, ERROR.

How can I filter only ERROR logs and how to forward to slack channel from ElasticSearch?

I have tested "Kibana Watcher" with "Slack Webhook" but it seems only for particular threshold and time based alert.

I want to forward real-time error message to slack channel **only one time** when new error happened in log.